# Use JS/Jquery to change DIV id ona seperate file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, xhtml

Hi I have a a bit of an issue. I am loading an affiliate banner, and the JS file that controls the size, width and other outputs can not be hosted on my server (not allowed by publisher).

**current config**

I have a div with an image inside it:

```
<div>
<img src="someimage.jpg" id="img=" />
</div>
```

and when you click on the image this div expands into a 300px width and 180 width survey people can fill out and submit.

so here is the issue:

the JS file that I can't touch has all the styles for the image, and I am trying to change that image size with something that matches my site. so I in my html file (where the JS is included) I hard coded:
    #img{height:100px; width:100px;} this worked fine and the image was reduced to 100x100, but the issue is that the survey was no longer expanding and was also set to 100x100.

so I am trying to get creative to find a good way to change the image size without downloading the JS file.  so there are 2 solutions I am thinking of:

1. use JS to call the function that sets the height and width and overwrite it
2. use JS to call the ID and change it in the html.

if you have a better way I am all ears :)

Comment: Can you post link to a sample page or the JS source? I see no reason for JS to be unable to change the height of your div.
*Also I assume id="img=" is a typo and should rather be id="img" ?

Comment: Any issues with using predefined classes in CSS with height and width? Then just use [addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) and [removeClass](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) with your elements to change how they look.

Comment: why not just set width & height as attributes on the img tag?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a class on the image(Changing the id isn't that elegant):

```
 .imgClass{height:100px; width:100px;}


<div>
    <img src="someimage.jpg" id="img" class="imgClass" />
</div>
```

In the onclick event of the image you can remove the class:

```
$("#img").bind("click",function(){
    $(this).removeClass('imgClass');
});
```

Or inline

```
 <div>
    <img src="someimage.jpg" onclick="$(this).removeClass('imgClass');" id="img" class="imgClass" />
</div>
```